# How does angular service (like ChangeDetectorRef) can get the component ref that used it?

Tags: javascript, angular

I wonder how does this line work:

```
this.ref.markForCheck();
```

Or:
  `this.ref.detach();`

While ref is: `ChangeDetectorRef`

I didn't see a way to get in a service the component that called you, so how does angular knows which component called it when I call `this.ref.detach();` and detach the right component?

I would expect a call like `this.ref.detach(this);` so I pass the reference to the component, but seems like angular service has a way to access the caller?

Added jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1hk7knwq/11788/
Look at the `test()` call, somehow the ref service is also getting the component instance without me explicitly passing it.

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm some time ago , I was also confused about this but I found this github issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14656#issuecomment-285814969  You can find there , that not every DI Token resolves to instance of some class, some like this `ChangeDetectionRef` is builtin and resolves to given component bound View, which got some Change-detector. So there is some mapping object where Your component-instance got attached view, which got own change-detector-ref.

Comment: @Take_Care_, thanks a lot! it was driving me crazy I had a feeling there is something deeper here that I miss.